# magento upgrad from 1.4.0.1 to 1.4.2.0

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.4

I am getting this error: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY' when upgrading magento.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try to find out which tables is meant – then check from which setup script the second entry having that ID (`7`) came from…

Comment: file name where error occured is mysql4-upgrade-1.3.99-1.4.0.0.php I think I do not need to run this file because I am not upgrading from 1.3.99 to 1.4.0.0.

Comment: Magento normally doesn't run setup files, that are not necessary for the current version. But updating Magento is a mess. Especially when having installed such a version as 1.4.

Comment: I tried to figure out from the file but did not find out where it is inserting to table and which table regarding to sales. Its a PHP code, it will take a lot of time to execute and debug that code.

Comment: I am renaming the file, so it will not executed and then run the upgrade again. Did this will effect my upgrade process?

Comment: upgrade has been complete but now I have missing some Order and invoice entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is complete solution to upgrade from any version because I tried step by step version upgrade of mageto but I faced the same problems.

[Magento upgrade takes too long and never completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes)