# magento upgrade form 1.4.0.1 to 1.7.0.2 I am missing order and invoices records

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.4, magento-1.7, duplicates

With reference to this question [magento upgrad from 1.4.0.1 to 1.4.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069119/magento-upgrad-from-1-4-0-1-to-1-4-2-0#comment17752166_13069119)

Now I have missing many records from orders and invoices. How to solve it and get my all orders and invoices.

More I also upgraded to 1.7.0.2 and it also have the same issue.

Comment: Can someone figure out to me what tables are related to orders and invoices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the tables related to sales and orders, also found what is the insertion order. As I mentioned in the previous question, there are errors when the upgrade is running. The errors are duplicate entries found in sales sql files. So I run the following queries and the upgrade is now progressing from sales tables.

```
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Please review this link, here is the complete solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes